# Can my cleric with the War Caster feat use a mace to deliver Inflict Wounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, feats, cleric

My Cleric has the War Caster feat, a mace in his right hand, and a shield in his left. He casts *inflict wounds*, which requires a touch attack to be executed against an opposing enemy, a goblin for instance.

If the cleric uses his mace as a means to touch the creature, would this function as a touch attack?  Would this deal mace damage in addition to the Inflict wounds? Why or why not?

Comment: Would the mace deal damage to the opponent?  Or would 'inflict wounds' be the only damage calculated?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the *Warcaster* feat does is negates the need to have one hand free to cast the Somatic component of spells, so long as your hands are occupied by either weapons and/or a shield.

It doesn't allow you to cast spells *through* a weapon.

*Inflict Wounds* allows you to make a melee *spell* attack not a melee *weapon* attack. As such, unless otherwise stated in the spell's description, only the spell damage is inflicted, not the weapon damage.

Comment: And given that your character's hands are full at the time, I believe the appropriate thing to do is to narrate your character performing the touch spell attack as a righteous hip-bump.

Answer (score 6):

### The feat lets you keep your mace in your hand while casting

While there is no "touch attack" in 5e D&D, let's walk through how *Inflict Wounds* works.

*Inflict Wounds* has both Verbal and Somatic components. [Somatic components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SomaticS) require (p. 203 PHB):

> free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

The simplest thing to do without the feat is to drop or sheathe the mace and cast *Inflict Wounds*, per the spell.  Dropping or sheathing the mace costs you neither an action nor a bonus action.  Refer to page 190 of the PHB and the ["Other Activity on Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#InteractingwithObjectsAroundYou) section:

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.

As well as the ["Interacting with Objects Around You"](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=73) sidebar:

> Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do in tandem with your movement and action:
>
> - draw or sheathe a sword

Since you could draw or sheathe a weapon as one such interaction, dropping or sheathing your mace leaves your hand free to cast that spell.

You can't cast the spell through your mace, though.  You need a free hand ...**unless you have the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/war-caster) feat** (PHB, p. 170).  In that case, *you can cast the spell with the mace in your hand*.

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

Because you have the feat, you can cast the spell and *Inflict Wounds* does the damage if you score a hit.  That spells requires that you roll for a hit.  (See page 205 of the PHB, and spell description on page 253 of the PHB).

> On a hit, the target takes 3d10 necrotic damage.

Your mace isn't part of that attack.